# How to grep multiple strings in different lines from an entire directory and sub directories on Linux terminal?

Tags: grep, search, pattern-matching

I want to match a pattern that have "John" & "Riya" & "bug".

Example_1:

```
//This file should match.
Hi John, How are you?
Riya, what is your age?
Fix this bug by end of the week.
```

Example_2:

```
//This file should not match.
Hi John, How are you?
Mike, what is your age?
Fix this bug by end of the week.
```

Comment: The title mentions "in different lines"; do you want to ensure that the strings definitely occur on _different_ lines? This would mean that a line containing both `John` and `Riya` would _not_ match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lookaheads are meant for these. Invoke grep in PCRE mode `-P`, and slurp mode `-z`. Then list the input file that satisfies the 3 lookaheads.
The `(?s:.....)` will make the dot `.` span newlines.

```
$ grep -Plz '(?s:(?=.*John)(?=.*Riya)(?=.*bug))'  file

$ grep -Plzr '(?s:.....)' .
```

Will recurse and list the matching files under the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` with several `-exec grep` in sequence to match each pattern:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q "John" {} \; -exec grep -q "Riya" {} \; -print
```

This is not as bad as it looks since `find` will stop at the first failing test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xargs:

```
grep -rlZ John . | xargs -r0 grep -lZ Ryia | xargs -r0 grep -l bug
```

`grep -rlZ John`  : Will recursively (`-r`) grep John in all files and print only the file names (`-l`). `-Z` will ensure that any unusual characters like newlines are printed and sent to the next command correctly.

`xargs -r0 grep -lZ Ryia` : xargs will give the filenames in the previous pipe as arguments to the next grep - which is looking for "Riya" . The `-r0` option to xargs is actually two options -both pertaining to handling unusual filename characters. This grep  searches for "Riya" in the files that already have "John", and passess those filenames to the next pipe

`xargs -r0 grep -l bug` : finally "bug" is searched in all files that already have "John" and "Riya"  and then the final list of files is printed.

Comment: ... unless any of the matching filenames (or directories) have spaces, tabs, or newlines in them...

Comment: @JeffSchaller, yes (and also single quote, double quotes, backslashes and depending on the `xargs` implementation, other whitespace or byte sequences not forming valid characters in the local). That syntax is GNU-specific anyway, so you might as well do: `grep -rlZ John . | xargs -r0 grep -lZ Ryia | xargs -r0 grep -l bug` which addresses all those issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add to @Rakesh_Sharma's answer

```
grep -rzl 'John\b.*Riya\b.*\bbug\b'  ./
```

the order of the patterns does not matter:

```
grep -l 'bug' "$(grep -l 'Riya' "$(grep -lr 'John' ./)")"
```

Comment: This appears to assume that the strings appear in a particular order.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda, fixed

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution from Rakesh Sharma, grep and awk can be very useful. However, matching far beyond grep can be handled by specialized codes, such as those in this snippet:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Input data file $FILE:"
head $FILE

pl " Results for glark, looking for \"John\" and \"Riya\" and \"bug\":"
# glark --no-filter -a -1 John -a -1 Riya bug --end-of-and $FILE
# glark --explain -a -1 John -a -1 Riya bug --end-of-and $FILE
glark -l -a -1 John -a -1 Riya bug --end-of-and $FILE
pe " Results for glark, inverse, expecting data2:"
glark -L -a -1 John -a -1 Riya bug --end-of-and $FILE

pl " Results for greple, looking for \"John\" and \"Riya\" and \"bug\":"
greple -l --block='(?s).*' 'John Riya bug' $FILE

pl " Results for rapgrep, looking for \"John\" and \"Riya\" and \"bug\":"
rapgrep -e=John -e=Riya -e=bug $FILE
pe " Results for rapgrep, reverse, expecting data2:"
rapgrep --reverse -e=John -e=Riya -e=bug $FILE
```

which will produce:

```
-----
 Input data file data[12]:
==> data1 <==
//This file should match.
Hi John, How are you?
Riya, what is your age?
Fix this bug by end of the week.

==> data2 <==
//This file should not match.
Hi John, How are you?
Mike, what is your age?
Fix this bug by end of the week.

-----
 Results for glark, looking for "John" and "Riya" and "bug":
data1
 Results for glark, inverse, expecting data2:
data2

-----
 Results for greple, looking for "John" and "Riya" and "bug":
data1

-----
 Results for rapgrep, looking for "John" and "Riya" and "bug":
data1
 Results for rapgrep, reverse, expecting data2:
data2
```

The first two have abilities beyond grep, but you will be trading features for speed. At our shop we decided to produce the third item, rapgrep, a grep-like code that did that specific function. The commented-out lines in the glark section allow you see some details of how glark is working.

If you are interested in obtaining the first two, here are some details:

```
glark   Search text files for complex regular expressions, grep (local man). (doc)
Path    : /usr/local/bin/glark
Version : 1.10.5
Length  : 23 lines
Type    : Ruby script, ASCII text executable
Shebang : #!/usr/bin/ruby2.1
Home    : https://github.com/jpace/glark (doc)
( But possibly better installed as "gem install glark", after
( installing ruby. Can also recurse.

greple  grep with multiple keywords (man)
Path    : ~/bin/greple
Version : - ( local: RepRev =, ~/bin/greple, 2017-07-02 )
Length  : 2390 lines
Type    : Perl script, ASCII text executable
Shebang : #!/usr/bin/perl
Home    : https://github.com/kaz-utashiro/greple (doc)

rapgrep Require all patterns grep. (what)
Path    : ~/bin/rapgrep
Version : 1.2
Length  : 307 lines
Type    : Perl script, ASCII text executable
Shebang : #!/usr/bin/perl
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 0):

Considering 2 files `example_1.txt` and `example_2.txt`:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*1.txt" -exec grep -E "John|Riya|bug" {} \;
```

If wildcard isn't enough you can use the `-regex` option from find